# loop my select options using input="number"?

Tags: javascript, loops, select-options

[Here is my Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/galonmark/42tsf07e/2/)

```
<input type="number" id="test" onkeydown="javascript:return event.keyCode==69? false:true" name="form_select" class="text" onchange="showDiv()">
<select id="hidden_div1" style="display:none;" name="form_select">
   <option value="0">No</option>
   <option value ="1">Yes</option>
</select>

<div id="allcontent1"></div>

<script>
  function showDiv(){
  allselect="";
    getSelectValue = parseInt(document.getElementById("test").value);
    if(getSelectValue > 0){
    for (let i=0;i<getSelectValue;i++){
        
       allselect+=document.getElementById("hidden_div1").style.display="block";}
    }else{
   document.getElementById("hidden_div1").style.display="none";
    }
    document.getElementById("allcontent1").innerHtml = allselect;        
}

</script>
```

I wanted to iterate my select elements, using javascript only

Comment: You are just changing the visibility inside the loop. You might need to collect the `.outerHTML`

Comment: if that so can you give me some ideas for me to learned? ;)

Comment: I've made changes in JS:  https://jsfiddle.net/gprxadn4/

Comment: thank u for the help but how about without pressing those up and down buttons of input numbers,

Comment: i mean how about you randomly put a any numbers in there.

Comment: The function called `onchange` so you should lose focus in order to trigger that function.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.